# VirtualBox Error 'drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message'

Tags: vbox

I am getting this error while restarting my vbox (OS: Ubuntu). It is throwing error as "failed to start docker container engine".
Kindly help me how to resolve this issue. Is there any way where I can stop the docker as I am not able to access the terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcLf.png)

Answer (score 3):

For me, I ran out of disk space.

I increased the virtual hard drive disk size from 10GB to 100GB, the error disappeared and it than booted normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have also seen this kind of error a few times after updating, resizing the partition helps solve this problem. I think that answer could be extended with steps how to do this, or at least provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

**Works sure**

**Step 1**: on screen enter exit as below

(initramfs)  **exit**

**Step 2**: Above command list disk space(/dev/sda1 ... sdan)

Note: change accordingly in below command

(initramfs) **fsck /dev/sda1 -y**

**Step 3**: reboot system or reboot not working simply exit

(initramfs) **reboot**

Or

(initramfs) **exit**

[image]

[image]